# Can't edit custom field for Users (Account update) in my Rails 4 app with Devise (Rails 4, devise 3, formtastic, geocoder)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rails-geocoder

I'm geolocating the user with geocoder and storing the value I get in the User's table  (in a attribute called user_country_name).

I am sure it has nothing to do with geocoder but **I don't manage to simply edit the country in User Account page.**

I tried to edit the email and the passwoird and it works but not the other custom fields i added compared to Devise basic form.

I think I've done all needed to update account attributes in Rails 4 but keep getting this error for 2 whole days!

```
ActionController::UnpermittedParameters at /
found unpermitted parameters: user_country_name
```

1. Here is my form for User info edit

   ```
      <%= semantic_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put, :class => 'form-vertical' }) do |f| %>

             <%= f.semantic_errors %>

               <%= f.inputs do %>
                 <%= f.input :email, :required => true %>   

                 <%= f.input :user_country_name,
                   :as         => :select,
                   :collection => COUNTRIES, # sends to a constant I have with all countries
                   :prompt     => true
                 %> 

                 <%= f.input :password, :input_html => { :autocomplete => "off" }, :hint => t("devise.registrations.edit_account_page.leave_blank_if_dont_want_to_change"), :required => false %>
                 <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :required => false %>                 
               <% end %>

               <%= f.actions do %>
                 <div>
                   <%= f.action :submit, :label => t("devise.registrations.edit_account_page.update"), :button_html => { :class => 'btn-primary' } %>
                 </div>
                 <div class="half-right-small return-login">
                 <%= link_to t("directions.back"), :back %>
                 </div>

              <% end %>

           <% end %>
   ```
2. here is my application controller

   ```
   class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

     protect_from_forgery

     include CountrySetter # handle localization through ip lookup and the I18n used
     include LocaleSetter

     # handle Cancan authorization exception
     rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
       exception.default_message = t("errors.application_controller_exception_messages.only_open_to_admin")
       if current_user # if it's user redirect to main HP
         redirect_to root_path,              :alert => exception.message
       else 
         redirect_to customerinterface_path, :alert=> exception.message
       end
     end  

     before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?  

     private      

       before_filter :authenticate_user_from_token!
       before_filter :authenticate_customer_from_token!

       def authenticate_user_from_token!
         user_email = params[:user_email].presence
         user       = user_email && User.find_by_email(user_email)

         if user && Devise.secure_compare(user.authentication_token, params[:user_token])
           sign_in user, store: false  # we are signing in user if it exists. sign_in is devise method to sign in any user
           redirect_to root_path       # now we are redirecting the user to root_path i.e our homepage
         end
       end


     protected

      def configure_permitted_parameters
         [:sign_up, :account_update].each do |sanitize_me|
           devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(sanitize_me) do |u|
             u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :user_country_name)
           end
         end
       end

       def devise_parameter_sanitizer
         if resource_class == User
           UserParameterSanitizer.new(User, :user, params)
         else # for customers
           CustomerParameterSanitizer.new(Customer, :customer, params)
         end
       end

   end
   ```
3. and finally the RegistrationsController form Devise:

   ```
   class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

   def update

   # added for upgrade to Rails 4
   account_update_params = devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update)

   # required for settings form to submit when password is left blank
   if account_update_params[:password].blank?
     account_update_params.delete("password")
     account_update_params.delete("password_confirmation")
   end

   @user = User.find(current_user.id)
   if @user.update(account_update_params) # Rails 4 .update introduced with same effect as .update_attributes
     set_flash_message :notice, :updated
     # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case his password changed
     sign_in @user, :bypass => true
     redirect_to after_update_path_for(@user)
   else
     render "edit"
   end
   end

   # for Rails 4 Strong Parameters
   def resource_params
     params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :user_country_name)
   end
   private :resource_params

   # used to update user-country by ip lookup when user signs up and associate newly signed-up user with a country
   # source - stackoverflow.com/questions/24294169/devise-sign-up-how-to-save-an-attribute-without-having-a-form-field-for-it-ra
   protected
     def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
       resource.update(user_country_name: set_country) #use concerns/CountrySetter loaded by ApplicationController
       root_path
     end

   end
   ```

**EDIT**

To answer some comments asking for the Route

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do

  # redundancy with below standard users 'root to' code. Goal: to easily be able to change
  # the page if decide one day that users should see a different page when they log in
  # used to be a bug- solved with: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2393#issuecomment-17544388
  authenticated :user do
    root to: 'static_pages#home', as: :authenticated_root
  end

  # Homepage for unauthenticated users
  # used to be a bug- solved with: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2393#issuecomment-17544388
  unauthenticated do
    root to: 'static_pages#home' # , as: :unauthenticated_root
  end

  # Routes for users
  devise_for  :users,
    :token_authentication_key => 'authentication_key', 
    :controllers              =>  { confirmations:  'confirmations', 
                                    registrations:  'registrations',
                                    sessions:       'sessions',
                                    passwords:      'passwords',
                                    unlocks:        'unlocks' }, 
    path: '', # inspired by Nitish solution to make devise urls custom (source: tackoverflow.com/questions/19889570/rails-devise-user-registration-route-post)
    path_names:   { :sign_in  => "signin",
                    :sign_out => "logout",
                    :sign_up  => "signup" }                   

  resources :users

  # Routes for customers
  devise_for :customers,
    controllers: {  registrations:  'customers/registrations', # inspired by stackoverflow.com/questions/20913157/devise-views-with-multiple-models
                    confirmations:  'customers/confirmations',
                    sessions:       'customers/sessions',
                    passwords:      'customers/passwords',
                    unlocks:        'customers/unlocks'  },
    path:         'advertiser', # inspired by Nitish solution to make devise urls custom (source: tackoverflow.com/questions/19889570/rails-devise-user-registration-route-post)
    path_names:   { :sign_in  => "signin",
                    :sign_out => "logout",
                    :sign_up  => "signup" }

  # Routes for the interface with reportings and private data for Customers
  # Customers interface HP can be accessed at /campaigns
  match '/customerinterface', 
   to:    'clientreporting_pages#index',
   path:  'campaigns',
   via:   'get'                                


  # Routes for all managed by Active Admin (deals creation, prizes creation...)
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  # Static Pages
  match '/help',            to: 'static_pages#help',          path: 'help',     via: 'get'
  match '/aboutus',         to: 'static_pages#aboutus',       path: 'about-us', via: 'get'
  match '/contact',         to: 'static_pages#contact',                         via: 'get'
  match '/howitworks',      to: 'static_pages#howitworks',    path: 'about',    via: 'get'
  match '/globalpresence',  to: 'static_pages#globalpresence',path: 'global',   via: 'get'
```

And here is the detailed log of error I get in my local console

```
Started PUT "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-08 19:55:50 +0200
Processing by RegistrationsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"geygeyegyegyegyegeykd7NwrVyAw=", "user"=>{"email"=>"emailtest@gmail.com", "user_country_name"=>"Germany", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"<span class="}
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 457 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms

ActionController::UnpermittedParameters - found unpermitted parameters: user_country_name:
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:372:in `unpermitted_parameters!'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:270:in `permit'
  devise (3.2.4) lib/devise/parameter_sanitizer.rb:66:in `permit'
  devise (3.2.4) lib/devise/parameter_sanitizer.rb:58:in `account_update'
  devise (3.2.4) lib/devise/parameter_sanitizer.rb:77:in `default_sanitize'
  devise (3.2.4) lib/devise/parameter_sanitizer.rb:24:in `sanitize'
  app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:11:in `update'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:483:in `_run__3174996646979711185__process_action__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:44:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:674:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/migration.rb:373:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__2636980444171422651__call__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.0.2) lib/quiet_assets.rb:18:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.0.5) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.5) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /home/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /home/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

**EDIT #2**

I tried everything that you guys proposed  but nothing worked. then i tried one thing:  I removed devise_parameter_sanitizer. then it works!! but should/can i remove this without compromising the security of the app? isn't this block important?

Here is the block I removed:

```
def devise_parameter_sanitizer
      if resource_class == User
        UserParameterSanitizer.new(User, :user, params)
      else # for customers
        CustomerParameterSanitizer.new(Customer, :customer, params)
      end
    end
```

What does it tell me about the problem ? maybe it's an important clue to the real bug but i don't get it:)

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: I have a feeling that this is not working right `[:sign_up, :account_update]` have you tried doing each in their own loop ?
try  

`devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) do |u|`

     `u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :user_country_name)` 

`end`

and another one for the `sign_up`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I'll try that tomorrow but I think i had already tried to decouple the two and it still did not work. Don't think it is the reason but i'll give a try tomorrow.

Comment: @Observer just tried it and it does not work. the problem does not come from your suggestion.

Comment: why is before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller? ..... not before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

Answer (score 0):

can you try this please

application controller

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
```

and

application Controller

```
protected

def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << [your params]
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << [your params]
end
```

Registrations controller

```
<!-- REMOVE -->
# added for upgrade to Rails 4
account_update_params = devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update)

# for Rails 4 Strong Parameters
def resource_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :user_country_name)
end
private :resource_params
```

let me know how this works out for you, you seem to be declaring your permitted params too many times in different places

Comment: Hi, I removed all the block you said and used your code but still get the same error found unpermitted parameters: user_country_name. I'm beginning to wonder if it's not built-in devise that user_country or sht like this gets automatically "not updatable": see here sth similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20836365/devise-rails-cannot-update-user-info. Maybe i should try to create a new column with a very different name , far from user_country, and see what happens...

Comment: dont see why that would be a problem..just thought of something...can you post your routes file please

Comment: i think you're right the name of the attribute has nothing to do with my pb but i'll try tomorrow (u never know!) but in reply to your request, i added my routes on the bottom of the question.

Comment: i also added the whole error log so you can see what I get

Comment: been having a look at your setup, and IMO i would have gone about the user roles differently, i would set flags in the user model perhaps so you dont have `devise_for :users`, `devise_for :customers` etc etc.. could be some confusion there.. my advice would be to branch off, take the app back to just one user for now with devise (would even consider getting rid of can can) and then add the permitted_params in the way i said and see if it works.. if it does you know you have a problem elsewhere

Comment: just tried to create a column with totally differenbt name but did not work: u were right. moving on to next proposals

Comment: @Richelewis tried everything on the page and nothing worked. then i tried one thing:  i removed devise_parameter_sanitizer. then it works!! but should/can i remove this without compromising the security of the app? isn't this block important? See my post edit

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this was to :

Create a true rest `controllers/users_controller` and to use Devise controllers just for `controllers/users/registration_controller`and `controllers/users/sessions_controller`.

Unset devise control of create/edit un `routes.rb`

```
devise_for :users,   controllers: {  registrations: "users/registrations", 
                                        sessions: "users/sessions" }
resources  :users
```

### Answer Update

In Rails 4 you must permit all parameters with `params.permit(params_list_to_allow)` or for rapid upgrade from Rails 3 `params.permit!` to pass mass assignment

Like this you have a normal controller for manage your `User` model likes other application controllers.

in `controller/users_controller.rb`

```
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'Errors.' }
      end
    end    
  end

  private 
    def user_params
      params.permit!
    end
```

Comment: Tried this but did not work. I tried everything on the page and nothing worked. then i tried one thing:  i removed devise_parameter_sanitizer. then it works!! but should/can i remove this without compromising the security of the app? isn't this block important? See my post edit

Comment: I used my solution because I didn't want to use devise_parameter_sanitizer (for decoupling devise feature from my big User model). If you use this method, the security is the same for all your models. P.S: You need to add allow your parameter with permit in Rails 4. I updated my reponse

Comment: not sure if it's the right answer but it's the closest so i gave you the bounty. I'll have to try this. I'm surprised i still have to add 'def user_params
      params.permit!
    end' because My code already included the params_permit in: def resource_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :user_country_name)
end
private :resource_params...but maybe sth was not working.